# New Aurelia Validation ! equals(expectedValue)

Tags: aurelia

The old way:

```
this.validator = this.validation.on(this)
    .ensure('baseContent.RedirectFrom')
        .isNotEmpty()
    .ensure('baseContent.RedirectTo')
        .isNotEmpty()
        .isNotEqualTo(() => { return this.baseContent.RedirectFrom }, 'Redirect from');
});
```

isNotEquals doesn't seem to exist in the new validation there is a `equals(expectedValue)`

I have considered doing a custom validation element however struggled as it passed through 'RedirectFrom' as undefined.

```
ValidationRules.customRule('notEqualTo',
        (value, obj, otherValue) => {
            return value === null || value === undefined || value === '' || otherValue === null || otherValue === undefined || otherValue === ''||  value === otherValue;
        }, 
        "must not match");

.ensure('RedirectTo').required().satisfiesRule('notEqualTo', this.baseContent.RedirectFrom)
.ensure('RedirectTo').required().satisfiesRule('notEqualTo', this.RedirectFrom)
.ensure('RedirectTo').required().satisfiesRule('notEqualTo', RedirectFrom)
```

Anyone see anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

> obj[propertyName]

CustomValidation.js

```
ValidationRules.customRule('mustNotMatchValue',
            (value, obj, valueToNotMatch) => {
                return value === null || value === undefined || value === '' || obj[valueToNotMatch] === null || obj[valueToNotMatch] === undefined || obj[valueToNotMatch] === '' ||  value !== obj[valueToNotMatch];
            }, 
            "must not match ${$config.valueToNotMatch}", 
            (valueToNotMatch) => ({ valueToNotMatch }));
```

baseContent.js

```
.ensure('RedirectTo').required().satisfiesRule('mustNotMatchValue', 'RedirectFrom');
```